# pymongo group by datetime

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Im trying to search through a collection and group records by date field which is a datetime.
I know pymongo converts those to the proper type on the background (ISODate or something like that).

Question is, since datetime objects have date, time, timezone.. how can i tell the group operator to use only the date portion? Because otherwise i dont get the desired grouping since time is preventing the records with same day, month, year to be grouped together.

```
db.test.aggregate([
        {"$group": {
             "_id": "$date", 
             "count": {"$sum": 1}
        }},
        {"$limit": 10}])
```

Result:

```
{u'ok': 1.0,
 u'result': [
  {u'_id': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 15, 18, 49, 9, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x318f210>),
   u'count': 1},
  {u'_id': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 15, 18, 36, 38, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x318f210>),
   u'count': 1},
  {u'_id': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 15, 18, 23, 56, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x318f210>),
   u'count': 1}]}
```

It would be nice to control the datetime information used to group,

- group by date only
- group by date and hour
- group by date, hour and minute
- etc.

Is there something like: (or some way of telling to use date only)

```
db.test.aggregate([
          {"$group": {
              "_id": "$date.date()",
              "count": {"$sum": 1}
          }},
          {"$sort": "_id"}
])
```

Or maybe there’s another way of dealing with this, any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can use the [Date Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) with [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and [$concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to tie it all together.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
        "_id" : { "$concat": [
            {"$substr": [{"$year": "$date"}, 0, 4 ]},
            "-",
            {"$substr": [{"$month": "$date"}, 0, 2 ]},
            "-",
            {"$substr": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$date"}, 0, 2 ]},
        ]},
        "count": {"$sum": 1 }
     }},
     {"$sort": { "_id": 1 }}
])
```

You could use just the date operators and make a document as in:

```
"day": { 
    "year": {"$year": "$date" },
   "month": {"$month": "$date"}, 
   "day": {"$dayOfYear": "$date"}
}
```

That works just as well. But this gives you a nice string. This makes use of the fact that `$substr` will cast from integer to string. If that ever gets added to the documentation.

Look at the [Date Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) documentation for usage on the other time divisions that can be used on dates.

---

Better yet, use date math to return a BSON Date:

```
import datetime

db.test.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$add": [
               { "$subtract": [
                   { "$subtract": [ "$date", datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) ] },
                   { "$mod": [
                       { "$subtract": [ "$date", datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) ] },
                       1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                   ]}
               ]},
               datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
           ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

Here [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) will be fed into the pipeline as a BSON Date representing "epoch". When you [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) one BSON Date from another the difference in milliseconds is returned. This allows you to "round" the date to the current day by again subtracting the [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) result to get the remainder of milliseconds difference from a day.

The same is true of [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) where "adding" a BSON Date to a numeric value will result in a BSON Date.

Comment: thanks! that works great (i've fixed the brackets on the $substr)